# What does "struct integer overflow" DeprecationWarning mean?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting a lot of these errors:

```
    /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rospy/src/rospy/msg.py:151: DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated
      msg.serialize(b)
```

Does anyone know what this is about?  I have not been able to track down the specific messages in my system that cause it.  I am running with CTurtle on Ubuntu 10.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10818/what-does-%22struct-integer-overflow%22-deprecationwarning-mean?/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, Python emits that warning when you serialize an integer that is wider than is being requested -- it basically means that you may be overflowing a message field.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2011-08-22**:
Yes, that seems to be it.  I found a place in my code that was using an int32 in a message field that was only uint8.